# SeekBar thumb animation

Tags: android, animation, seekbar

My problem is twofold.
I have a seekBar at the moment it isn't customized but I fear that in the future it will need to be.
My problems surround the thumb image:

1. My seekBar thumb needs to be clickable as I want an action to take place when touched this I managed to achieve using a onTouchlistener the problem is I would like a visual feedback image when the thumb is clicked, This I tried to achieve with a drawable selector with no avail.
2. Second problem is that I want to animate my seekbar thumb on orientation change. This I have NO idea how to do...

any help will be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**
The animation that I'm trying to achieve is a rotation so the image will always be "upright"

and the code that I tried to use for the click feedback is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:drawable="@drawable/camera_button_feedback" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/camera_button_feedback" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/camera_button_icon"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: What sort of an animation are you looking to apply? Also, it would be greatly helpful if you could post the code you've attempted thus far in achieving the seekBar thumb clicks, so that people who'll attempt to help you (like myself) can easily import that code and attempt to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what I did after long deliberation was create a view under the thumb which progressed with the thumb and made the seekbar's thumb invisible in order to get the touch events and just animated the underlying view as needed

Answer (score 0):

Solution to problem 1.) : I've personally tested this so I can assure you it works and you **WILL** get visual feedback.

1.) Create a folder called 'xml' in your project and then add an XML file called thumb_drawable.xml to it. In this file define the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item 
android:state_pressed="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/seek_thumb_pressed">
</item>
<item 
android:drawable="@drawable/seek_thumb_normal">  
</item>
</selector>
```

'seek_thumb_normal' is the default android seekbar thumb and the link to download that image is this : http://www.tutomobile.fr/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/seek_thumb_normal.png . And 'seek_thumb_pressed' is a modified version of the default android seekbar thumb that just has a different color. Now, you can easily replace this with some other image you want by placing that image in your drawable folder and then referencing that name here.

2.) Here's the code I used to define the SeekBar in my layout file:

```
<SeekBar android:id="@+id/seekbar"
         android:max="100"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="30dp" 
         android:minWidth="30dp"
         android:minHeight="30dp" 
         android:thumb="@xml/thumb_drawable"/>
```

Problem 2: Now, this is where I'm a bit confused because you said "The animation that I'm trying to achieve is a rotation so the image will always be "upright", Android, by default, handles the rotation of the image when you change the orientation of the phone from portrait to landscape and thus you image remains upright by default. I just tested this out myself on Ice-cream Sandwich and the seekbar thumb rotated by itself when I changed the orientation. So, unless I've misunderstood or you had something else in mind, you don't need to animate anything when dealing with orientation transformations. Do let me know if you had something else in mind and I'll help you resolve that.

Comment: thanks for the help. will try what you suggested soon even though its close to what I tried already...about the animation I disabled orientation change...so the changes don't happen automatically... guess I should have mentioned that

Comment: wait, so then what were you referring to when you said "I want to animate my seekbar thumb on orientation change." and "I'm trying to achieve is a rotation so the image will always be "upright"? And now you said you have disabled orientation change (I assume you mean you have locked the orientation to portrait) so if you've locked the orientation then your screen will never rotate right?

Comment: OK tried the selector file, doesn't work now when I start dragging the thumb the icon changes and doesn't turn back. note that I'm doing the work with an onTouchListener and not seekbarchangedlistener..About the animation I did lock the orientation to portrait but I handling orientation changes anyways with a orientationListener...

Comment: I solved the selector problem by changing the images manually in the code ... not a nice solution but effective...

Answer (score -4):

check the following snippet it may help u somewhat...

```
         seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekBar.setOnTouchListener(this);
          private void updateSeekProgress() {
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        seekBar.setProgress((int)(((float)mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / lengthOfAudio) * 100));
        handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how this solves my problem in any way